# Impedance seen by the inverting terminal

Tags: operational-amplifier

Actually it is given in Sedra smith that  to reduce input offset current effect is to use a resistance at non-inverting terminal of the opamp whose value is same as the **DC resistance seen  by  the  inverting  terminal.**

I am actually confused that what is meant by "resistance seen by the inverting terminal"?   Is he referring to calculate Thevenin resistance from inverting terminal?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. You got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what it says precisely in sedra smith but you can't do anything about input **offset** current. However, if you mean input **bias** current then that is eradicated by making the dc resistance seen by both inputs the same value. So, if there is a 100k feedback and a 100k input resistor to the inverting terminal then, ideally, you should have 50k seen by the non-inverting terminal to 0V. Thus **bias** currents produce an error voltage at each input terminal that is identical and thus cancel out.

[image]

Input **offset** current is the difference between the **bias** currents on each input terminal and this is not so easily got rid of.

Of course if the **bias** current is only 1nA and you are using 1k resistors (i.e. quite small values) then the worst case dc voltage error produced (if you don't have a resistor in the inverting input) is 1 uV - probably far less than the input offset voltage of the op-amp and therefore not worth bothering about.

See [this](http://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-038.pdf) (MT-038: Op Amp Input Bias Current - Analog Devices) for further reading on the subject.